# Using jetty how to rewrite parameters of an Eclipse RAP application?

Tags: java, url-rewriting, jetty, jetty-9

I'm trying to rewrite the parameters of a webapplication (Eclipse RAP). The parameters are my own, not handled by RAP.

The goal is to rewrite `/rap/viewer/locale/fr` to `/rap/viewer?locale=fr`.

But already a simple test is failing:

```
RewritePatternRule rule = new RewritePatternRule();
rule.setPattern("/test/viewer");
rule.setReplacement("/rap/viewer");
rewriter.addRule(rule);
```

The problem is that the webapplication needs resources which seem to be in relative paths, so:
`/rap/rwt-resources/resources.js` turns into `/test/rwt-resources/resources.js`. Which then results in a blank screen.

Any idea on how I can overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite is for paths only.

It does not apply to Query Parameters, URI parameters, URI templates, Path Parameters, Hosts, Ports, and Schemes.

Since your requirements also span multiple contexts, you would likely need to write your own Jetty level Handler, that sits before all of your Contexts in the Handler tree which does the logic you are interested in accomplishing.

But seeing as you are using Eclipse RAP, there's really no good access to the raw Jetty Server handler tree from within Eclipse RAP (a requirement to accomplish this).